# Dynamic root Key in ActiveModel Serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

I am using `Rails 5` and `Acive Model Serializer (0.10.6)` in my project. I need below format of JSON

```
{
   "account_lists": {
    "0": {
            "id": 1,
            "description": "test tets test tets"
          },
     "1": {
            "id": 2,
            "description": "test tets test tets"
          }
      }
}
```

`0`,`1` keys would be the index of the object.

I tried with below code, But result is not coming

`account_serializer.rb`

```
class AccountSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :custom_method

  def custom_method
    { object.id => {id: object.id, description: object. description } }
  end
end
```

`accounts_controller.rb`

```
render json: @accounts, root: "account_lists", adapter: :json
```

Result is

```
{
"account_lists": [
    {
        "custom_method": {
            "46294": {
                "id": 46294,
                "description": "test tets test tets"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "custom_method": {
            "46295": {
                "id": 46295,
                "description": "test tets test tets"
            }
        }
   ]
 }
```

Could you please help me to get the result.

Comment: If you don’t need a root, you can set the root to false. Like this `render json: @accounts, root: false, adapter: :json`

Comment: @SujayGavhane I need root, But I wants custom root for object root.

Comment: @Jenorish have you figure it out, i just need to work on smth like this.

Comment: @7urkm3n haven't tried yet.

Comment: @Jenorish what kind an error yr getting ?

Comment: @7urkm3n Added answer Please check.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this in two ways, using serializers or without using serializers.

To make this work with serialzers we need to write some meta programing. something like this

```
class AccountSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes

    def initialize(object, options = {})
        super
        self.class.send(:define_method, "#{object.id}") do
            {
                "#{object.id}": {
                    id: object.id,
                    description: object.description
                }
            }
        end
    end

    def attributes(*args)
        hash = super
        hash = hash.merge(self.send("#{object.id}"))
    end
end
```

this will produce results like this

```
{
    "account_lists": [
        {
          "19":{
              "id":19,
              "description":"somethign here "
            }
        },
        {
            "20":{
                "id":20,
                "description":"somethign here "
            }
        },{
            "48":{
                "id":48,
                "description":"somethign here"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

if you want json response to exactly what you have mentioned in question, you better to go with a custom library class that build json for you

```
class BuildCustomAccountsJson

  def initialize(accounts)
    @accounts = accounts
  end

  def build_accounts_json(accounts)
    _required_json = {}

    @accounts.map do |account|
     _required_json["#{account.id}"] = { id: "#{account.id}", description: "#{account.description}" }
    end

    _required_json
  end

end
```

and in controller action, we can use this class

```
def index
  ...
  ...

  @accounts_json = BuildCustomAccountsJson.new(@accounts).build_accounts_json

  render json: @accounts_json, root: "accounts_list"
end
```

this will produce json like this

```
{
   "account_lists": {
    "0": {
            "id": 1,
            "description": "test tets test tets"
          },
     "1": {
            "id": 2,
            "description": "test tets test tets"
          }
      }
}
```

That's all.